# It's/I'm acting in your best interest/interests

Tags: plural-forms, collocations

The plural version is more common according to Google ngram. It is also used as an example in Cambridge's dictionary.

> [It's **in his interests** to keep careful records](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/interest)

However, I would like to know whether the plural and the singular versions are equally perfect to use without sounding unnatural.

If there is any difference, of course I would like to learn about it.

Singular:

> It's/I'm acting **in your best interest**

Plural:

> It's/I'm acting **in your best interests**

Google ngram is provided for both with "your" and without:

*[your best interest,your best interests,best interest,best interests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your%20best%20interest%2Cyour%20best%20interests%2Cbest%20interest%2Cbest%20interests&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20best%20interest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20best%20interests%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%20interest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%20interests%3B%2Cc0)*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of the word [interest](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/interest) in Macmillan's Dictionary

**Sense 5**

`[countable/uncountable] an advantage or benefit to someone or something`

**be in your (own) interest(s)** (=bring an advantage or benefit):

> *It's in their own interest to cooperate.*

**have someone's (best) interests at heart** (=want to help them):

> *He claims he has only my best interests at heart.*

**be in someone's/something's (best) interest(s)** (=bring an advantage or benefit):

> *The president doesn't believe the plan is in the best interest of the company.*

---

However, **The FreeDictionary** gives two versions for the idiom "... at heart"

**have someone's best interest(s) at heart**

to make decisions based on someone's best interests.

> I know she was only doing what would benefit her, but she said she had
>   my best interests at heart.

---

And from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/interest), it seems that *interests* is generally more common.

**in the interests *(or interest)* of something**

2 **For the benefit of:**

> in the *interests* of security we are keeping the information confidential
>
> One such principle holds that space is to be explored and used ‘for
>   the benefit and in the *interests* of all countries.’
>
> We are doing so because it is in our best *interests* and in the
>   interests of our citizens.
>
> The Government should act in their *interests* and not just in the
>   *interests* of the elite who can afford to build nursing homes.

---

It seems it is a question that may bug some native speakers too!

A relevant question on [the Web](http://community.babycenter.com/post/a29777579/question_for_grammar_junkies?cpg=2): **question for grammar junkies.....**

> Is it... "..in the child's **best interest**?" or "...in the child's **best
>   interests**?"
>
> Does the answer change if you change "**child**" to "**children**?"

**NB:** Since the proof was in Macmillan's dictionary already, I should consult more than **one** dictionary from now on. In fact, many times I find clearer answers and definitely some examples when they are not provided in Cambridge's. I like Cambridge's look and feel more and it is a decent work to be honest.

**Edit:**
This one is even more interesting!

[in the interest v. in the interests](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1192562)

**Edit 2**

With this, the post should come to an end

**[Best interest or interests?](http://www.thestar.com.my/story/?file=%2F2008%2F4%2F10%2Flifefocus%2F20817440)**
MIND OUR ENGLISH

The Star Online
, Thursday April 10, 2008

> IS IT grammatically correct to say “I have your best interest at
>   heart” or “I have your best interests at heart”?
>
> Assuming both of the above are correct, in the following sentence,
>   which would you say works better?
>
> “Your priorities are important so believe us when we say that we have
>   your best interest(s) at heart.”
>
> – Viv
>
> 1) Both are grammatically correct, but when “interest” means
>   “advantage” or “benefit”, the plural “interests” is more often used.
>
> 2) I would go for “best interests”.